# Debugging Python Module from within Github Repo in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, setup.py, pdb

I have a python library in github I want to debug. The library has setup.py as well as a pip released package. So I can install this module using either pip install git-sim or python3 setup.py install.

This module adds a command to the path and I can execute in terminal with git-sim .

**Main Problem: I want to clone the github repo and open vscode inside the cloned repo and debug the code getting executed while I am running the command from the terminal. The breakpoints should hit the file inside the repo.**

Link to the github Repo: https://github.com/initialcommit-com/git-sim

I went searching with these requirements. Best I could come up so far is

1. An edit mode in setup.py which can be started by `pip install -e .` . While I ran this command and was successful I did not see a way to debug it.
2. How do we debug a module in Vscode? Give this code in launch.json

```json
    {
        "name": "Python: Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "git-sim",
        "justMyCode": false,
    }
```

But while I am running this I am getting an error, no module named git-sim  even though the same command works outside the debugger in the terminal. i.e both git-sim and python3 -m git_sim

Any suggestion of where  I maybe going wrong? Or if there is some alternative option I have not considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. I made a mistake in assuming the terminal command git-sim and the actual python -m git_sim were same.

Module Name and Terminal commands are different. So if we modify launch config from "module":"git-sim" to "module":"git_sim" it works. Modified config given below:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "git_sim",
    "justMyCode": false,
}
```

Comment: Hi, @MingJie-MSFT Thanks for the reply. Waiting for the completion of 48 hours window to accept my own answer.